# Receiver and transmitter issue

Tags: receiver, transmitter, long-range-drone, electronics, homemade-drone

I am trying to build a drone from scratch. I purchased Fly Sky FS-CT6B 6 transmitter. but unfortunately the receiver is not supporting PPM communication. I am using pixhawk 2.4 as flight controller.

I tried purchasing PPM encoder, but it is not functioning properly. Can I purchase receiver which supports PPM communication from FLYSKY and bind with Fly Sky FS-CT6B 6 transmitter? Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to use PPM ? Perhaps the pixhawk supports IBUS serial communication which most flysky receivers support.

What receiver do you have anyway ia6b ?

Also read up on this link : https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-rc-systems.html

Comment: Nope, I am using FS-R6B receiver. I read somewhere that it doesn't support PPM and IBus. So i am looking for a receiver which is compatible with Fly Sky FS-CT6B 6CH and can support PPM/IBus. is there any option?